# Create a new row in a dataframe that is a calculation based on existing rows

Tags: r, dplyr, group

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9UyB.png)

In the attached image I would like to create and add the c variable rows rto the dataframe.  Row c is row a - row b (by date etc). Have tried using dplyr but not getting there....

```
variable <- c(a,b,a,b) 
date <- c(jan 22,jan 22, feb 22,feb 22) 
amount <- c(100,20,100,20)
```

```
DF:
variable   date   amount
--------   ----   ------
a         Jan 22   100
b         Jan 22   20
c         Jan 22   80
a         Jan 22   100
b         Jan 22   20
c         Jan 22   80
```

Comment: Provide example data and expected output, do not post images of data.

Comment: Hi, sure.  How dod I do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is better to perform mathematical operations across columns than between rows, so the best way to do this is to first `pivot_wider` (or reshape) the data into a wide format, then do the `mutate`, and then `pivot_longer` back to the long format that you want.  Using `tidyverse`:

```
DF |>
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "date" , names_from = "variable", values_from = "amount") |> 
  mutate(c = a-b) |>
  pivot_longer(c(a,b,c), names_to = "variable", values_to = "amount")


  date   variable amount
  <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
1 jan 22 a           100
2 jan 22 b            20
3 jan 22 c            80
4 feb 22 a           100
5 feb 22 b            20
6 feb 22 c            80
```

Comment: Does not quite work for me.  In reality the dataset looks more like this:

DF:
variable      date short name      date long name        city short      city long           amount
--------       ------------------      -------------------      ----------      ----------          -----------
ab                  Jan 22   20
c                   Jan 22   80
a                   Jan 22   100
b                   Jan 22   20
c                   Jan 22   80

Comment: my answer corresponds to the data in the question, if your real dataset has a different structure that affects the answer can you update the question details?

Comment: variable      date short name      date long name        city short      city long           amount
--------       ------------------      -------------------      ----------      ----------          ---------
a                   Jan 22                        01/01-2022               LA               Los Angeles        100
b                  Jan 22                         01/01/2022               LA               Los Angeles          20                             
c                   Jan 22                        01/01-/2022              LA               Los Angeles          80

Comment: Thanks George.  I should have made my example clearer, sorry.  Basically, there is more than one variable in each section; value_from etc and I get a missing arguments error when I try?

Comment: without you properly updating the details in the question text it is difficult to update the answer.  But in short you just need to add more elements to `id_cols` in the `pivot_wider` call.  So `pivot_wider(id_cols=c("date", "city",...)...` etc

Comment: Thanks George, I will try and re-post the question.  Problem is the the variable  column has a short name and a long name, so I think that craetes a problem in the mutate part?

Comment: I just reposted in clearer /  better format (hopefully!)